# Erro a tentar gerar ficheiro PDF com o mesmo nome

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Ao tentar gerar ficheiros PDF, muitas das vezes me deparo como o erro:

> Mensage: The process cannot access the file 'D:....\23381708.pdf' because it is being used by another process.

Que me indica que o ficheiro não pode ser criado, porque já está a ser usado por outro processo.

Este problema ocorre quando estou a tentar gerar um documento com o mesmo nome de outro que tenha criado instantes antes.

Para tentar contornar esta situação, estou a tentar:

```
//Definir tipo de documento
Document doc1 = new Document();
doc1.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
doc1.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
doc1.NewPage();

var ficheiroAbs = Path.Combine((pastasLer.FirstOrDefault().PastaDestGARTratada + "/2Via"), nomeDoc);
//abrir documento para escrever
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, new FileStream(ficheiroAbs, FileMode.Create));//Erro ocorre nesta linha
doc1.Open();

//código criar documento

doc1.Close();
doc1 = new Document();
```

No entanto, por vezes (não é sempre) retorno sempre aquele erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou forçar o `Dispose()` ao fim da criação do documento:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, new FileStream(ficheiroAbs, FileMode.Create));//Erro ocorre nesta linha
doc1.Open();

//código criar documento

doc1.Close();
doc1.Dispose();
doc1 = new Document();
```

Ou numa maneira mais performática:

```
//Definir tipo de documento
using (Document doc1 = new Document()) 
{
    doc1.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
    doc1.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
    doc1.NewPage();

    var ficheiroAbs = Path.Combine((pastasLer.FirstOrDefault().PastaDestGARTratada + "/2Via"), nomeDoc);
    //abrir documento para escrever
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(ficheiroAbs, FileMode.Create)) {
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, fileStream);
        doc1.Open();

        //código criar documento
    }

    doc1.Close();
}
```

Comment: Com o uso do `.Dispose();` acontece o mesmo, ou seja, por vezes dá o erro. Vou experimentar da segunda sugestão

Comment: Da segunda forma também acontece o mesmo

Comment: O que estou a fazer, é criar o ficheiro e envio por email em anexo. Poderá ter alguma coisa a haver com o envio do email e ficar bloqueado no processo?

Comment: Não, acho que é o `FileStream` anônimo que está causando isso.

Comment: Então tenho de o iniciar/criar antes? Ou igualar a algo antes do write?

Comment: Sim, e fazer o `Dispose()` logo após.

Comment: Estou a colocar o `using` e o `Dispose()` após fechar o documento. É isso que queres dizer?

Comment: Melhor eu editar a resposta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19125/discussion-between-cesarmiguel-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).